# How do I install PHP PECL uploadprogress library using Macports?

Tags: macports, drupal, status

In Drupal 8, when in admin/reports/status, there is a note that says,

> "...that only one upload at a time is supported. It is recommended to use the PECL uploadprogress library if possible.".

How do I install the PHP PECL uploadprogress library using Macports?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
pecl install uploadprogress
```